# Central solution for switching proxy settings

Tags: linux, arch-linux, gnome, proxy

At work we have a proxy server, at home I do not have one. In total I have 5 virtual machines and a bunch of other programs which do not support using the system proxy settings.

When I come home from work I always have to go into many settings to switch the proxy off. I thought there has to be a smart solution to make my daily work easier.

I talked to colleagues and there was the idea of a local proxy which is used in every program and virtual machine and this proxy either forwards everything to the proxy when I am at work or just let everything through when I am at home. But I cannot find anything via google that would help me setting up this proxy or suggest any other solution for this problem.

Does anybody have some idea?

My setting: - Arch Linux 64Bit - gnome shell

Comment: Are you talking about HTTP(S) or other protocols? What method of configuring a proxy do these programs support (`http_proxy` environment variable, proxy.pac, …)?

Comment: Maybe you can use nginx with the upstream directive, putting your work proxy and the requested destination. Then changing balance to prefere proxy if accessible.

Comment: @Gilles I am talking about proxy in general. Not a specific protocol

Comment: @X4fyr I will have a try with that, thanks

Comment: @RuthiRuth There's no such thing as a “proxy in general”. A proxy forwards a particular protocol. This can be done at various layers: an HTTP(S) proxy, a TCP proxy (SOCKS), an IP proxy (VPN), … So, once again: what kind of proxy is it? Answers would be radically different.

Comment: @Gilles we have a proxy for https, http and ftp and socks I think. At least I had to insert the proxy to all of the proxy-fields in gnome-proxy-settings...